# Applescript if contains a word

Tags: if-statement, applescript, contain

Here is my script :

```
set APPS to { "facebook", "Minecraft"}
if appName contains APPS then
    display notification "app founds" with title "Apps"
```

I also try with

```
if appName is in APPS then
```

but in this example, if the app found is "Minecraft: Story Mode" then the script will fail (won't detect anything) how can I make the script to detect this ?

Kind regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to check if an item **in a collection** contains a substring you need a repeat loop

```
set APPS to {"facebook", "Minecraft"}
repeat with anApp in APPS
    if appName is in anApp then -- or anApp is in appName depending on which is the substring
        display notification "app founds" with title anApp
        exit repeat
    end if
end repeat
```

Comment: Thank you, the issue is if the variable found is "Minecraft: Story Mode" instead that wouldn't work or maybe I should write down every variable that would fix it